# Validate date with Moment.js according to culture format

Tags: javascript, validation, date, momentjs

I must validate a date according to the date format of the culture.. For example I could have the need to validate the date either for english culture ("MM/DD/YYYY") or italian culture ("DD/MM/YYYY").

For some reason, the date is validate always with english culture.
So for example I want to validate an English format date:

```
moment.locale('en'); // <-- I set the culture

moment('12/13/2015').isValid(); // <-- Return true, ok
moment('13/12/2015').isValid(); // <-- Return false, ok
```

Now I want to validate the same date, changing just the culture:

```
moment.locale('it'); // <-- I set the culture

moment('12/13/2015').isValid(); // <-- Return true, but it should be false
moment('13/12/2015').isValid(); // <-- Return false, but it should be true
```

How do I have to use moment.js to validate date?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For validation with known format you can use:

```
moment('13/12/2015',['DD/MM/YYYY']).isValid();
```

Try this way:

```
> moment.locale('it')
'it'
> var m = moment('13/12/2015', 'L');
undefined
> m.isValid()
true
> m.format()
'2015-12-13T00:00:00-05:00'
```

Comment: I don't have a known format... it depends on the culture I choose at the start of the application....

Comment: Simone: Your "known format" is most likely to be 'l', 'll', 'lll', or 'llll', or the uppercase variants, here.  (Pick one)

Comment: Just one point: .isValid() doesn't prevent from changing month by day and viceversa